# How to join and convert chunks of .ts files to mp4

Tags: video, linux-distribution

Could anyone suggest a valuable tool (optionally, but not mandatory, under Linux [ openSUSE]) for that?

- join ~300 .ts files
- convert video to another format (optionally, mp4; but it can be anything else that could be viewed on any OS) without loosing audio

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it was as simple as it could ever be %)

- order files in proper way, select all, rename selection to `video#`
- join all chunks into one files by `cat video*.ts > full.ts`
- convert to mp4 by `ffmpeg -i full.ts -c:v libx264 -c:a copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc final.mp4`